# Get values from sap.m.Table

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to get the values from a sap.m.Table without clicking  a specific entry?

With an event I can get the values by the actual context but what I need is to get the whole items with the specific characteristic.

For example my table has the following columns (column D is not invisible):

```
 A B C D
```

with the entries shown below:

```
 A B C D

 1 2 3 4
 4 b 2 1
```

What I need now is the first row for example:

1 2 3 4

I want to write something like

`table.getItem("A")[0]`

to get 1 as a result.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the Items in the table using getItems(), which will give you an Array of Items. You can then get the bindingContext for any of the Items.

```
var iRowIndex = 0;  //For First row in the table
var oTable = this.getView.byId("myTable"),
    oModel = oTable.getModel(),
    aItems = oTable.getItems();

if(iRowIndex < aItems.length){
  oModel.getProperty("ColA",aItems[iRowIndex].getBindingContext());
}
```